# planes with flow layout

Tags: java, spring-security

I have one main plane and 4 subplanes named as x,y,z,button plane
    and I have 3 toggled switches in each plane respectively. When I am clicking first toggle button I have able to show the one plane below the x plane.
    When I off the switch it has to disappear. The functionality is working but when I am trying to switch of the button the plane is disappear and adding gap in between those planes.

public class OptionScreen extends Screen implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

```
    public OptionScreen(B b) {
        super(b);
        font = b.getFont(18, Font.BOLD);
        this.b = ckupgrade;
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE.getColor());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        titleLabel = new JLabel();
        titleLabel.setFont(font);
        titleLabel.setText(Messages.getString("LBl")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        titlePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        titlePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        titlePanel.setBackground(color.WHITE.getColor());
        titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        titlePanel.add(titleLabel);
        font = b.getFont((float) 13.5, Font.BOLD);

        Switch = new JSwitchBox("", "****");//$NON-NLS-1$
        Switch.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        Switch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        Switch.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        Switch.setOpaque(false);
            Switch.addActionListener(this);

        WebletsCheckBox = new JLabel(" Additional Apps");//$NON-NLS-1$
        WebletsCheckBox.setOpaque(false);
        WebletsCheckBox.setFocusable(false);
        WebletsCheckBox.setFont(b.getFont((float) 13.5, Font.PLAIN));

        BuiltInApps = new JPanel();
        BuiltInApps.setBackground(Color.GRAY_TINT10.getColor());
        BuiltInApps.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        BuiltInApps.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        BuiltInApps.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        BuiltInApps.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        BuiltInApps.add(Switch);
        BuiltInApps.add(WebletsCheckBox);

        PanelSwitch = new JSwitchBox("", "****");
        PanelSwitch.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        PanelSwitch.setSelected(true);
        PanelSwitch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        PanelSwitch.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        PanelSwitch.addMouseListener(this);
        PanelHeading = new JLabel("******");
        PanelHeading.setOpaque(false);
        PanelHeading.setFont(b.getFont((float) 13.5, Font.PLAIN));

        pPanel = new JPanel();
        pPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY.getColor());
        pPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    pPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        pPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        pPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        pPanel.add(pPanelSwitch);
        pPanel.add(pPanelHeading);
                font = b.getFont(15, Font.BOLD);

                NumberLabel = new JLabel(Messages.getString("********"));
        NumberLabel.setFont(font);
        NumberLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 50));
        PortNumberLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(125, 30));
        pTextBox = new JTextField("9100");
        pTextBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE.getColor());
        pTextBox.setBorder(new RoundBorder(Color.GRAY.getColor(),
                Color.WHITE.getColor(), 14, 14));
        pTextBox.setFont(ckupgrade.getFont(15, Font.BOLD));
        pTextBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 30));
        pTextBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(75, 30));
        NumberPanel = new JPanel();
        NumberPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY.getColor());
        NumberPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(NumberPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        NumberPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
        NumberPanel.add(NumberLabel);
        NumberPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
        NumberPanel.add(pTextBox);
        NumberPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        OptionsSwitch = new JSwitchBox("", "***********");//$NON-NLS-1$
        OptionsSwitch.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        OptionsSwitch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        OptionsSwitch.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(30, 50));
        OptionsLabel = new JLabel("*********");
        OptionsSwitch.setOpaque(false);
           OptionsLabel.setFont(ckupgrade.getFont((float) 13.5, Font.PLAIN));
        OptionsSwitch.setSelected(true);
        OptionsSwitch.addMouseListener(this);
        OptionsPanel = new JPanel();
        OptionsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        OptionsPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        OptionsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        OptionsPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 30));
        OptionsPanel.add(OptionsSwitch);
        OptionsPanel.add(OptionsLabel);
        font = b.Font(15, Font.BOLD);

        Label = new JLabel(
                Messages.getString("*****"));//$NON-NLS-1$
        Label.setBackground(Color.GRAY.getColor());
        Label.setFont(b.getFont(12, Font.BOLD));
    Label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225, 50));
        sLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(225, 30));
sField = new XTextField("5");
Field.setBackground(Color.WHITE.getColor());
    sField.setBorder(new RoundBorder(Colore.WHITE.getColor(),
                Color.WHITE.getColor(), 14, 14));
        sField.setFont(b.getFont(13, Font.BOLD));
        sField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        sField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        sField = new XTextField("5");//$NON-NLS-1$
        sField.setFont(font);
        sField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));
        sField.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(40, 30));
        sField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(40, 30));
        sField.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        sField.requestFocus();
        sPanel = new JPanel();
    sPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        sPanel.setBackgroundColor.GRAY.getColor());
        sPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
        sPanel.add(Label);
        sPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5, 0)));
        sPanel.add(sField);
        sPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        closeButton = new XButton(
                Messages.getString("***"),//$NON-NLS-1$
                Theme.WhiteOnBlue);
        closeButton.setFocusable(false);
        closeButton.setFont(font);
        closeButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        closeButton.setFont(be.getFont(15, Font.BOLD));
        closeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 37));
        closeButton.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 37));
        closeButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 37));
        closeButton.addActionListener(this);

        removeLabel = new JLabel("Remove");//$NON-NLS-1$
        removeLabel.setFocusable(false);
        removeLabel.setForeground(Color.RED.getColor());
        removeLabel.setFont(b.getFont(15, Font.BOLD));
        removeLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 37));
        removeLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 37));
        removeLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 37));
        removeLabel.addMouseListener(this);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY.getColor());
        titlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        titlePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        titlePanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 40));
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
        buttonPanel.add(removeLabel);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(200, 40)));
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton);
        buttonPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY.getColor());
        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setBorder(new RoundBorder(Colo.GRAY.getColor(),
                Colo.GRAY.getColor(), 10, 10));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        mainPanel.add(titlePanel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 30)));
        mainPanel.add(pPanel);
        mainPanel.add(lBuiltInApps);
        mainPanel.add(sPanel);
        mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 27)));
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == OptionsSwitch) {

        if (!(sPanel.getParent() == mainPanel)) {
            OptionScreen.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                OptionScreen.this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                OptionScreen.this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 330));
                mainPanel.remove(buttonPanel);
                mainPanel.add(sPanel);
                mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
            } else if (sPanel.getParent() == mainPanel) {
                OptionScreen.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                OptionScreen.this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                OptionScreen.this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.remove(sPanel);
            }


        } else if (e.getSource() == PanelSwitch) {
            if (!(NumberPanel.getParent() == mainPanel)) {
                OptionScreen.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 380));
                OptionScreen.this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 380));
                OptionScreen.this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 380));
                mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 380));
                mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 380));
                mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 380));

                mainPanel.remove(BuiltInApps);
                mainPanel.remove(sPanel);
                mainPanel.remove(buttonPanel);

                mainPanel.add(NumberPanel);
                mainPanel.add(BuiltInApps);
                mainPanel.add(sPanel);
                mainPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 27)));
                mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

            } else if (NumberPanel.getParent() == mainPanel) {
            OptionScreen.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                OptionScreen.this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                OptionScreen.this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 280));
                mainPanel.remove(NumberPanel);
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == removeLabel) {
            close();
            }

    }

please suggest me how to remove the gaps .

I am using Flow layout
```

Comment: Show some code.